# Alternative to iotop for non-root user without sudo privileges

Tags: process, monitoring, io, non-root-user

I'm looking for an alternative to iotop. Here's my situation:

1. I want to find out if a program is accessing the hard drive a lot while running.
2. iotop requires root/sudo privileges.
3. My account is on someone else's system so I'm not allowed to have root or sudo privileges.

Is there an alternative to iotop I could use?

Comment: You could use a combination of `top`, specifically watching for 'wait' states, and `vmstat`.

Answer (score 27):

To reference a few more tools.

## htop

- http://hisham.hm/htop/
- https://github.com/hishamhm/htop

Command line tool, packaged in most distributions, is able to show the I/O without root privileges but only for your processes.

- run [`htop(1)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/htop.1.html), you'll find an interface similar to [`top(1)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/top.1.html)
- hit <kbd>F2</kbd> to enter the configuration
- use <kbd>↓</kbd> to select "Columns"
- use <kbd>→</kbd> to select "Available Columns"
- use <kbd>↓</kbd> / <kbd>↑</kbd> to select the I/O informations you want (ie: IO_READ_RATE, IO_WRITE_RATE, IO_RATE) and <kbd>F5</kbd> to add them to the "Active Columns"
- save with <kbd>F10</kbd>
- use <kbd><</kbd> / <kbd>></kbd> to select the I/O column to affect the sort order

---

## glances

- https://nicolargo.github.io/glances/
- https://github.com/nicolargo/glances

Command line tool with a web mode, not widely packaged but easy to install (ie: `pip install glances`).

---

## netdata

- https://my-netdata.io/
- https://github.com/firehol/netdata

Web interface, can be run without root privileges, not yet packaged (require compilation).

Comment: I have been using htop for so long and didn't know about this feature. Thanks!

Comment: There are also `iptraf` and `iptraf-ng`, nice ncurses consol tools. But these projects seem to [be abandoned](https://github.com/bearstech/iptraf-ng/issues/3). :(

Comment: `iptraf*` does only monitor network I/O

Comment: When I do as suggested for htop, it only displays "no permission" in the respective columns. Seems like I still need sudo rights for viewing this information.

Comment: Yeah htop definitely can't show IO_RATE etc. without root.

Comment: erm, that's what I wrote "you can see IO* **for your processes**" or more exactly "Permission to access this file is governed by a ptrace access mode PTRACE_MODE_READ_FSCREDS check" (from [procfs](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/procfs.5.html))

Answer (score 6):

The only thing that comes close is `iostat` from the [sysstat suite](http://sebastien.godard.pagesperso-orange.fr/) which also works for regular users, or maybe `atop -d` (fails with a floating pointing exception here).

A very similar question was asked on ServerFault: [In absence of `iotop`, which command is most appropriate for finding I/O-bound processes?](//serverfault.com/q/260818)

`iotop` doesn't work for regular users any more due to a security fix in the kernel: see e.g. [Red Hat bug report: *Netlink error: Operation not permitted*](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=742883)

For the same reason, you probably cannot display other processes' I/O stats on that level as regular user.